# Functions in an RKHS look like sums of kernels?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Recently, I heard that intuitively any function $f$ in a RKHS $\mathcal H$ looks like a sum of kernels. Can someone explain this intuition and can it be made precise?

Comment: see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Properties) last bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Following @g-g's comment, $\mathrm{span}\{ K_x \mid x \in X\}$ is dense in $\mathcal H$.

$K_x$ is the function in $\mathcal H$ associated with the evaluation functional $L_x$:
$$ L_x(f) := f(x) = \langle f, K_x \rangle.$$